# Craft3e: cabal install not in scope: Applicative

Tags: haskell

I am attempting to install the code for "Haskell: The Craft of Functional Programming", 3rd edition.

I'm using GHCi, version 7.6.3 on Centos version 7.

Then:

```
cabal unpack Craft3e
cd Craft3e-0.1.1.0/
cabal install
...
[29 of 67] Compiling CalcParseLib     ( Calculator/CalcParseLib.hs,    dist/build/CalcParseLib.o )
Calculator/CalcParseLib.hs:132:10:
Not in scope: type constructor or class `Applicative'
Failed to install Craft3e-0.1.1.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
Craft3e-0.1.1.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I have attempted this installation multiple times, but cannot
overcome this error.

Could I use something other than "cabal install"?

I have plenty to learn about Haskell before I get to this example,
but it would be great to know the installation is fine!  :)

Comment: Can you use a newer GHC (>=7.10)? It looks like that package wasn't tested with older versions. Upgrading would be easier than editing it to make it compile.

Comment: Yes, upgrading works. I updated to a ghc 8.0.2. I had some problems with the transaction lock, but I just rebooted and it cleared up.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

1. Install [an older version of the *Craft3e* package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Craft3e-0.1.0.10), with e.g. `cabal unpack Craft3e-0.1.0.10`.
2. Find [`Calculator/CalcParseLib.hs`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Craft3e-0.1.1.0/src/Calculator/CalcParseLib.hs) in the source files you have downloaded with `cabal unpack` and add a...

   ```
   import Control.Applicative
   ```

   ... line next to the other `import` lines at the beginning. I suspect you will have to do the same with other modules, if the same error shows up elsewhere after you do this change, and there might be other issues of a similar nature.
3. Install a newer version of GHC (7.6.3 is from 2013). Though the default CentOS repositories won't offer that, there are other options, such as an unofficial Fedora repository and a manual installation. See [this page](https://www.haskell.org/downloads/linux) for instructions.

#3 is the definitive solution. If you just want to get started with the book right now, though, you can go for #1 and leave the reinstall for later.

---

For the sake of reference, here is a brief explanation of the problem (I will use some unfamiliar terms, but you will soon enough learn about them as you study Haskell). There is an important type class called `Applicative` which, for historical reasons, wasn't as well integrated with the rest of the core libraries as it should be. This situation was corrected in GHC 7.10, which both included `Applicative` in the Prelude (the module which is imported by default in Haskell programs) and made it necessary to add `Applicative` instances in a number of places where they were missing. The code in the  *Craft3e* package was updated so that these `Applicative` instances were in place (cf. [this entry in the book's blog](http://www.haskellcraft.com/craft3e/Blog/Entries/2016/9/1_Updating_the_code_in_hackage.html)), but the `import Control.Applicative` line, which would be necessary to make the updated code work in older GHCs that do not have `Applicative` in the Prelude, wasn't added, leading to the error that you are seeing.

Comment: Yes, this works. I updated to a ghc 7.6.3. I had some problems with the transaction lock, but I just rebooted and it cleared up. I hope that in the future I can repay you kind attention by helping others.  :) ;)

Comment: @TrailingDots Glad it helped! Just one thing about your comment: perhaps you meant you installed a newer GHC (such as the current 8.0.2), as 7.6.3 is what you had before?